# Django template language - remove item from a list

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Just a quick question: is there a way to remove an item from a list in the Django template language?

I have a situation where I'm iterating through one list, and printing the first item in another list. Once the first item is printed I want to remove it from that list.

See below:

```
{% for item in list1 %}
     {{list2.0}}
     #remove list2.0 from list2
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over list excluding some elements? If yes, you can always put `if` statment inside `for` loop body.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I just edited to include an example of what it is I am trying to do exactly

Comment: I wouldn't really put the logic in your template. Also, that's a list2 item you're displaying, while looping through list1; is that correct?
I *think* you can use `pop` inside the template, provided your list is really a list, and not a queryset (otherwise, in your view, do `queryset = list(queryset)`. Then, in your template, try `{{ list2.pop }}`. I'm also not sure if you can provide an argument to pop, something along the lines of `{{ list2.pop|forloop.counter }}`. 
Finally, you could write your own `pop` tag that does exactly this. I can probably come up with some code for that if you like.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your efforts, as advised it isn't a good idea to remove an item from a list in the Django template language, I'm going to look for another solution, but for anyone who is curious you can indeed use pop to acheive this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your list1 and list2 are indeed lists and not querysets, this seems to work:

```
{{ list2 }}  {# show list2 #}
{% for item in list1 %}
    {{ list2.0 }}
    {# remove list2.0 from list2 #}
    {{ list2.pop.0 }}
{% endfor %}
{{ list2 }}  {# empty #}
```

Note that `pop` does not return in this case, so you still need {{ list2.0 }} explicitly.

Comment: {{ list2.pop.0 }} are you certain this doesn't raise an error like "pop function doesn't have 0 attribute" ?

Comment: Tested this, and it worked. See also Ruth's second comment to her question.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to filter out the item in the view if at all possible. Otherwise you can add in an if or if not statement inside the for loop.

```
{% for item in list%}
    {% if item.name != "filterme" %}
        {{ item.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete an item but you can get the list without a certain item (at a constant index)

```
{% with list2|slice:"1:" as list2 %}
...
{% endwith %}
```

Of course, nesting rules apply, etc.

In general, I you find yourself doing complex data structure manipulation, just move it to Python - it'd be faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in template tag. I understand that you don't want to print first item of `list2` if `list1` is not empty. Try:

```
{% for item in list1 %}
     {{list2.0}}
     ...
{% endfor %}

{% for item in list2 %}
     {% if list1 and forloop.counter == 1 %}
         # probably pass
     {% else %}
         {{ item }}
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is not a good idea to manipulate the content of the list in templates.